# Where can I learn the complete mathematics involved in LDA?

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, lda, dirichlet

I have come across Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) on multiple occasions while reading about sentiment analysis and recommender systems.

Where can I find good reading material which explains the concept in depth, especially by taking an example?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to DS.SE!

I believe the [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf) paper by Blei, Ng, and Jordan (all big names in AI/ML/NLP) is a point to start. They provided the math foundation as well as multiple examples.

See: Blei, David M., Andrew Y. Ng, and Michael I. Jordan. "Latent dirichlet allocation." Journal of machine Learning research 3.Jan (2003): 993-1022.